# How do I find the last DDL of a procedure which is inside an ORACLE package?

Tags: oracle, plsql, metadata, plsql-package

I know how to find the last DDL for standalone procedures. Is there a way to do it for procedures written inside a package?

Comment: You can't update a single procedure in a package to begin with, you can only update the whole package.

Comment: Now you know why integrating a proper source control system (svn, git, whatever) can be so important. Who is changing what, when - and hopefully not treating your database as a source control system.

Comment: Well, how do you find ( the last DDL for standalone procedures ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not. In any of `USER_`/`ALL_`/`DBA_` `OBJECTS`, `LAST_DDL_TIME` column is related to the whole object - in your case, a package. Procedures that are part of the package aren't *tracked*.

So, you know when package was modified, but can't tell which part was it.

Comment: Yeah what I figured as well.